# Odd Behavior Magento Order Collection Event

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to integrate the ERP that I work with and Magento. I've mostly accomplished this however I'm having some problems trying to get order statuses (shipments, invoices, etc...) to update from the ERP into Magento. Right now I'm trying to hook into the **sales_order_collection_load_before** event within Magento and then make an API call that goes and finds the current status within the ERP for any orders that are not completed/closed.

If there is a better way to handle this I don't have to use the **sales_order_collection_load_before** event but I am curious why this event works the way that it does.

Lets dive in, here is my observer code:

```
public function getOrderCollectionStatus ( $observer ) {

    Mage::log(" _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____", null, 'customEvent.log');

    // Added the registry/register code to deal with the event firing twice
    if ( Mage::registry('do_not_fire_event_multiple_times') ) {
        Mage::log(' _____ EVENT COMPLETE (already fired) _____ ', null, 'customEvent.log');
        return $this;
    }
    Mage::register('do_not_fire_event_multiple_times', true);

    Mage::log(" Before Retrieving Event ", null, 'customEvent.log');

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $collection = $event->getOrderCollection();

    Mage::log(" Before Foreach ", null, 'customEvent.log');

    foreach ( $collection as $order ) {
        Mage::log(" Order ID: " . $order->getId(), null, 'customEvent.log');
    }

    Mage::log(' _____ EVENT COMPLETE (everything finished) _____ ', null, 'customEvent.log');
    return $this;

}
```

When that code executes here is the log file output.

```
 _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____                   
 Before Retrieving Event                             
 Before Foreach                                      
 _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____                   
 _____ EVENT COMPLETE (already fired) _____          
 Order ID: 13                                        
 _____ EVENT COMPLETE (everything finished) _____    
 _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____                   
 Before Retrieving Event                             
 Before Foreach                                      
 _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____                   
 _____ EVENT COMPLETE (already fired) _____          
 Order ID: 13                                        
 _____ EVENT COMPLETE (everything finished) _____    
 _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____                   
 Before Retrieving Event                             
 Before Foreach                                      
 _____ STARTING EVENT (v3.0) _____                   
 _____ EVENT COMPLETE (already fired) _____          
 Order ID: 13                                        
 _____ EVENT COMPLETE (everything finished) _____
```

As you'll see, it appears to be firing the event again when I run the `getOrderCollection()` method. I tried to prevent this going into an infinite loop by adding the `Mage::register`.

I still get the following output in the **/var/reports/** and the page fails to load.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:65:"Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "13" already exist";i:1;s:4714:"#0 C:\Development\webservers\magento-1.9.2.4-0\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(582): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
```

I have a lot of questions about what is going on:

1. Why does the event fire 3 times? I would have thought the code I added for the `Mage::register` would have prevented this from executing after the first time.
2. Why do I get the error about duplicate data, in theory I'm not adding anything to the collection I'm only looping through what was already in that collection.
3. Is this the best way to handle retrieving order information from a third-party product?

When I remove the call to `getOrderCollection()` I no longer get the error message and the page loads fine. How can I manipulate the collection if retrieving it causes a duplicate error?

Another thing to note is that if I switch to the **sales_order_collection_load_after** event everything works fine with no errors. The problem now is that if I update and save an order in the collection the changes don't display on the page until the page is refreshed (default theme, inside of the view order page).

*I've edited this post in an effort to make it more readable*

Comment: What event are you observing?

Comment: I'm sorry, sales_order_collection_load_before

Comment: You'll be able to get more help if you describe to us **what you're trying to achieve with this observer call**.

Comment: I'm trying to update the status on orders before the user sees them. My goal was to hook into the **sales_order_collection_load_before** event and update any orders that are not closed with a new status from the ERP (if applicable). I've integrated Magento with the ERP that I work with and this is the last step.

Comment: I added a section about my goals to the top of the post and I bolded certain areas in an effort to make it more clear about which event I'm using.